# ¿How to use "readfile" if my file is outside the current folder?

Tags: php

I have a little problem and I'm not sure how to approach it/fix it.

I have a file that it's going to show me a certain PDF File. That PDF File is in another folder. A little example it would be like this:

1. MyCurrentProject/PHP/ShowFile.php
2. MyCurrentProject/PDF_Files/TestFile.pdf

So in my "ShowFile.php" I have this:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=prueba');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Rangers: bytes');
readfile("../PDF_Files/TestFile.pdf");
```

In "readfile()" I want to display that "TestFile.pdf" but I'm not sure how do I need to put the route to that file.

I know that I could use `Header("Location: ../PDF_Files/TestFile.pdf")`, but in this case I need to do it this way.

Or I cannot retrieve a file from outside the folder when using "readfile"? Or do I need to specify the route in a different way?

UPDATE:

I tried to use `__DIR__`, but I don't know how to use it. I would be doing stuff like this:

```
readfile(__DIR__."/../PDF_Files/TestFile.pdf")
```

UPDATE NUMBER 2:

Huge mistake by me. I forgot to mention that the file that I'm trying to access is in a virtual directory, so obviously (I guess) it was never going to find that file giving it the root like that. Now, what I did right now is this:

```
readfile("MyPage.com/Folder/PDF_Files/TestFile.pdf")
```

"Folder/PDF_Files" is my virtual path, so now I only have to give the right file (in this case is "TestFile.pdf")...My bad for the poor explanation before, sorry.

Comment: The path relation depends on the invocation script. If unsure, use `__DIR__`

Comment: Ok, going to check how to use that..So by using __DIR__ I would be able to achieve what I'm trying to with that file?

Comment: Given the locations of the files you show, your path should work.

Comment: @CarlosHernandez When you remove the `header()` statements, do you get any error message when you try to read the file with `readfile()`?